# Silverlight Xap Signing Failed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, silverlight

Visual Studio 2015 stopped signing my Silverlight Xap package after I reinstalled Windows. The error returned from the output window is:

> MSBUILD : error : Xap packaging failed. Cannot locate the signing tool SignTool.exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing The Windows 8.1 SDK fixed this issue. You can download it [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk).